# Zkteco Event Listener Not Working in ASP.NET Web Services Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, zkteco

we are planning to develop ASP.Net webservices for methods provided in Zkteco SDK.

One of the web-service is to Connect to the device. After invoking "Connect_Net(string IPAdd, int Port)" method, the connection is successful, also in the method, we register few events such as below:-

```
public bool Connect_Net(string IPAdd, int Port)
        {
            if (objCZKEM.Connect_Net(IPAdd, Port))
            {
                //65535, 32767
                if (objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 32767))
                {
                    // [ Register your events here ]
                    // [ Go through the _IZKEMEvents_Event class for a complete list of events
                    objCZKEM.OnConnected += ObjCZKEM_OnConnected;
                    objCZKEM.OnDisConnected += objCZKEM_OnDisConnected;
                    //objCZKEM.OnEnrollFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnEnrollFinger;
                    objCZKEM.OnEnrollFingerEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerExEventHandler(ObjCZKEM_OnEnrollFingerEx);
                    objCZKEM.OnNewUser += ObjCZKEM_OnNewUser;
                    objCZKEM.OnFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnFinger;
                    //this.objCZKEM.OnVerify += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(ObjCZKEM_OnVerify);
                    objCZKEM.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(zkemClient_OnAttTransactionEx);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

But after connection, those events (OnEnrollFinger, On Clock-In etc..) are not getting invoked in ASP.NET Webservices.

Similar listeners work fine in a windows form application.

Can you please advice on how to resolve this?, should the above events be registered in a background thread?, if yes then how to do so?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did it in windows forms application and then pass data to the web API

Comment: Thank you, but how do i develop a seamless solution, where get-data and listeners work properly?

Comment: I would suggest you separate the listeners - using windows form/service, to pass real-time data to web api/service. And use web service to expose data to other applications

Comment: @user3875039 its happening the same, did you resolve it?

Comment: @GonzaloArzeno I only used the `OnAttTransactionEx` event and its working fine in my case using windows application running in background.

Comment: If you are out of luck getting the event listeners working, you may use the `ReadTimeGLogData` to read logs between two dates

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I dont want a background application, and also, I need the real time event because its for enrolling people